# jQuery Plugin to "Bold" Matched Letters (the way Google Search Engine displays results)

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, plugins

Is there any jQuery Plugin to make "Bold" matched letters in a search query?

Like in any search engine, after a query is typed, the matches letters are made bold in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html).

Use the css:

```
.highlight { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: probelm with this. I think this plugin does simple prefix match. so for stuff like `$('h3').highlight('hig')` it works. But lets say my query is `hig ter`. Where both `hig` and `ter` words basically represent `highlight terms`. then doing `$('h3').highlight('hig ter')` does not highlight...

Comment: Anything more comprehensive? With so many plugins for jQuery out there, is there not one which replicates the search engine type of "bold" matched letters?

Comment: @MovieYoda - you can call the plugin multiple times with different words. Check the comments on the plugin's page: `$.each(words.split(" "), function(idx, val) { $('#text').highlight(val); })`

Comment: interesting... Right now exploring Alex's custom plugin for this purpose.